# Python: calculate probability for each value in a column to be valid

Tags: python, pandas, statistics, probability

I have a pandas dataframe like this:

```
+-----+----------+
| No  | quantity |
+-----+----------+
|   1 |    100.0 |
|   2 |    102.3 |
|   3 |    301.2 |
|   4 |    100.6 |
|   5 |    120.9 |
| ... |      ... |
+-----+----------+
```

How can I calculate the probability for each value that it does fit into the dataset (in dataframe above all do except of No.3). The idea is using the standardized normal distribution and calculate the probability, that a value (or more extreme one) would occur. In this case, probability that No.3 occurs is almost zero because it is far from all other values.

I know how to do this on paper for each value:

1. calculating z-score
2. find the corresponding value in the standard normal probabilities-table
3. if value is below average of the distribution, the probability is 1-probability

so desired output is something like this:

```
+-----+----------+--------+
| No  | quantity |  prob  |
+-----+----------+--------+
|   1 |    100.0 | 99,85% |
|   2 |    102.3 | 99,81% |
|   3 |    301.2 | 00,00% |
|   4 |    100.6 | 99,90% |
|   5 |    120.9 | 74,30% |
| ... |      ... | ...    |
+-----+----------+--------+
```

How can I realize that in python?

Thank you :)

Comment: Wouldn't the number of standard deviations be a more useful measure?

Comment: Can you show us what you've already tried?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some comments on your solution: if you're already using scipy, you can just use [scipy.stats.mstats.zscore](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.stats.mstats.zscore.html) rather than writing your own zscore calculation, and there's no need to import numpy to calculate the mean of a pandas series:

```
df= pd.DataFrame(columns=['No','quantity'], data=[[1,100.0],[2,102.3],[3,301.3],[4,101.3],[5,101.3],[6,120.3]])
mu=df.quantity.mean()
sig=df.quantity.std()
df['z']=scipy.stats.mstats.zscore(df.quantity)
df['prob'] = 0.0

for idx,row in df.iterrows():
    if row.quantity < mu:
        df.at[idx,'prob'] = 1 - (scipy.stats.norm(mu,sig).pdf(row.quantity))
    else:
        df.at[idx,'prob'] = scipy.stats.norm(mu, sig).pdf(row.quantity)
```

You also can avoid the iteration over the dataframe using apply:

```
df= pd.DataFrame(columns=['No','quantity'], data=[[1,100.0],[2,102.3],[3,301.3],[4,101.3],[5,101.3],[6,120.3]])
mu=df.quantity.mean()
sig=df.quantity.std()
df['z']=scipy.stats.mstats.zscore(df.quantity)
df['prob']=df['quantity'].apply(lambda x: scipy.stats.norm(mu,sig).pdf(x) if x > mu else 1 - scipy.stats.norm(mu,sig).pdf(x))
```

Comment: thank you for the suggestions. I wrote my own calculation for z-scores because I'm thinking about using median (or mode) instead of mean. In the original dataframe, there are lots of outliers and they effect the results in a negative way. what do you think? :)

Comment: @MaMo Do you mind sharing your code?

Answer (score -1):

Found my mistake, this is the answer to my question:

```
df= pd.DataFrame(columns=['No','quantity'], data=[[1,100.0],[2,102.3],[3,301.3],[4,101.3],[5,101.3],[6,120.3]])

df['z'] = (df.quantity - df.quantity.mean())/df.quantity.std(ddof=0)
mu = np.mean(df.quantity)
sig = df.quantity.std()
df['prob'] = 0.0

for idx,row in df.iterrows():
    if row.quantity < mu:
        df.at[idx,'prob'] = 1 - (scipy.stats.norm(mu,sig).pdf(row.quantity))
    else:
        df.at[idx,'prob'] = scipy.stats.norm(mu, sig).pdf(row.quantity)
```

Output is:

```
   No  quantity         z      prob
0   1     100.0 -0.513775  0.995560
1   2     102.3 -0.482472  0.995502
2   3     301.3  2.225906  0.000629
3   4     101.3 -0.496082  0.995527
4   5     101.3 -0.496082  0.995527
5   6     120.3 -0.237493  0.995159
```